# resvg Rust, SVG rendering as blank png

Tags: svg, rust

Could someone please explain to me why the resulting PNG file is blank?

```
pub fn render_svg_directly(svg_data: &str) -> Option<Pixmap> {
    println!("svg_dat: {}", svg_data);
    let opt = Options::default();
    let rtree = Tree::from_str(svg_data, &opt).ok()?;
    let pixmap_size = rtree.size;
    let mut pixmap = Pixmap::new(pixmap_size.width() as u32, pixmap_size.height() as u32)?;
    resvg::render(&rtree, tiny_skia::Transform::identity(), &mut pixmap.as_mut());
    pixmap.save_png("test_output.png").expect("Failed to save pixmap to PNG");
    Some(pixmap)
}
```

```
let svg_data = fs::read_to_string("../test.svg").expect("Failed to read SVG file");
let pixmap = plutonium::render_svg_directly(&svg_data).expect("Failed to render SVG");
```

output:

```
zeke plutonium_tester$ cargo run
   Compiling plutonium v0.1.0 (/Users/zeke/dev/plutonium_farm/plutonium)
   Compiling plutonium_tester v0.1.0 (/Users/zeke/dev/plutonium_farm/plutonium_tester)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1.18s
     Running `target/debug/plutonium_tester`
svg_dat: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 28.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
         viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="enable-background:new 0 0 100 100;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
        .st0{fill:#92278F;stroke:#9E1F63;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
<rect class="st0" width="100" height="100"/>
</svg>

rtree: Tree { size: Size { width: NonZeroPositiveF32(FiniteF32(100.0)), height: NonZeroPositiveF32(FiniteF32(100.0)) }, view_box: ViewBox { rect: NonZeroRect { left: 0.0, top: 0.0, right: 100.0, bottom: 100.0 }, aspect: AspectRatio { defer: false, align: XMidYMid, slice: false } }, root: Group { id: "", transform: Transform { sx: 1.0, kx: 0.0, ky: 0.0, sy: 1.0, tx: 0.0, ty: 0.0 }, abs_transform: Transform { sx: 1.0, kx: 0.0, ky: 0.0, sy: 1.0, tx: 0.0, ty: 0.0 }, opacity: NormalizedF32(FiniteF32(1.0)), blend_mode: Normal, isolate: false, clip_path: None, mask: None, filters: [], bounding_box: None, stroke_bounding_box: None, layer_bounding_box: None, children: [Path(Path { id: "", visibility: Visible, fill: Some(Fill { paint: Color(Color { red: 146, green: 39, blue: 143 }), opacity: NormalizedF32(FiniteF32(1.0)), rule: NonZero }), stroke: Some(Stroke { paint: Color(Color { red: 158, green: 31, blue: 99 }), dasharray: None, dashoffset: 0.0, miterlimit: StrokeMiterlimit(10.0), opacity: NormalizedF32(FiniteF32(1.0)), width: NonZeroPositiveF32(FiniteF32(1.0)), linecap: Butt, linejoin: Miter }), paint_order: FillAndStroke, rendering_mode: GeometricPrecision, data: Path { segments: "M 0 0 L 100 0 L 100 100 L 0 100 Z", bounds: Rect { left: 0.0, top: 0.0, right: 100.0, bottom: 100.0 } }, abs_transform: Transform { sx: 1.0, kx: 0.0, ky: 0.0, sy: 1.0, tx: 0.0, ty: 0.0 }, bounding_box: None, stroke_bounding_box: None })] } }
```

I have tried different SVGs from both inkscape and illustrator formats.

Answer (score 2):

You **must** call [`postprocess`](https://docs.rs/usvg/0.38.0/usvg/struct.Tree.html#method.postprocess) after parsing the [`Tree`](https://docs.rs/usvg/0.38.0/usvg/struct.Tree.html) as stated in the documentation:

> Must be called after parsing a usvg::Tree.

Here is the fixed `render_svg_directly` function:

```rust
pub fn render_svg_directly(svg_data: &str) -> Option<Pixmap> {
    println!("svg_dat: {}", svg_data);
    let opt = Options::default();
    let mut rtree = Tree::from_str(svg_data, &opt).ok()?;
    rtree.postprocess(PostProcessingSteps::default(), &fontdb::Database::new());
    let pixmap_size = rtree.size;
    let mut pixmap = Pixmap::new(pixmap_size.width() as u32, pixmap_size.height() as u32)?;
    resvg::render(&rtree, tiny_skia::Transform::identity(), &mut pixmap.as_mut());
    pixmap.save_png("test_output.png").expect("Failed to save pixmap to PNG");
    Some(pixmap)
}
```

Note however that this will only work if the SVG does not contain inline text, otherwise you would need to transform that text into *paths* in the postprocessing before rendering, like so:

```rust
let mut fontdb = fontdb::Database::new();
fontdb.load_system_fonts();

let mut rtree = usvg::Tree::from_str(&svg_data, &opt).unwrap();
let steps = usvg::PostProcessingSteps {
    convert_text_into_paths: true,
};
rtree.postprocess(steps, &fontdb);
```